# Can we mention a tag via Incoming Webhook in Microsoft Teams Adaptive Card?

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am trying to send an adaptive card with mentioning a tag (custom user group in a team).

Example Request -
Url - https://xx.webhook.office.com/webhookb2/xx-xx-xx-xx-xx@xx-xx-xx-xx-xx/IncomingWebhook/xx/xx-xx-xx-xx-xx

```
{
    "type": "message",
    "attachments": [
        {
        "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
        "content": {
            "type": "AdaptiveCard",
            "body": [
                {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": "Hi <at>TAG NAME</at> Testing Tagging via Incoming Webhook."
                }
            ],
            "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
            "version": "1.0",
            "msteams": {
                "entities": [
                    {
                        "type": "mention",
                        "text": "<at>TAG NAME</at>",
                        "mentioned": {
                          "id": "TAG ID",
                          "name": "TAG NAME"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

The output of this message ->

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TeUl.png)

Didn't get any notification of being tagged, also not getting any information related to this tag on hover.

Git Issue - https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/8265

Tried mentioning tag with several ways but nothing seems to be work. Need to mention tag while sending messages via Incoming Webhook.

Comment: According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/channel-and-group-conversations?tabs=dotnet#mention-tags-in-an-adaptive-card you would also need `"type": "tag"` under the `"mentioned"` key **but** even then it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Currently only user mention is supported in Incoming webhook.
Mentioning tag is not yet supported.
You can request this feature using [Microsoft Teams Feedback portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472).

Comment: Vote here: https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/a25adb53-5cbe-ed11-a81b-000d3a0450e3